# IOS/Objective-C/CoreData: Adding new managed objects to an MOC

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I want to add some new managed objects to an entity in core data. These managed objects are also represented by a class

Is it necessary to do the following each time?

```
 NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Steps" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        // Initialize Record
        NSManagedObject *blankStep = [[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
```

Alternatively, if I have an array of these objects, can I merely add a new object to the array and then save the context?

```
NSMutableArray <Steps *> *theNewSteps = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:20];
Steps *blankStep = [[Steps* alloc] init];
[theNewSteps addObject: blankStep];
```

Am confused about what is going on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it necessary to do the following each time?

Yes, either that or this:

```
NSManagedObject *blankStep = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Steps" inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext];
```

Either way instantiates a new object and inserts it into the managed object context.

> Alternatively, if I have an array of these objects, can I merely add a new object to the array and then save the context?

No. Core Data doesn't know about your array, so it doesn't know if you change that array. Also, this line:

```
Steps *blankStep = [[Steps alloc] init];
```

Will fail because it tries to create a new `Steps` instance but doesn't call the designated initializer for the class. You can't use `init` for managed objects, you need to use either your first code snippet or the version I mentioned above.

Comment: Thank you, Tom.  The voice of authority.

Comment: If I want to add this new step to the set of steps linked to another object in a many to one relationship in core data, can I just write:  _item.step = [NSSet setWithObject:blankStep]? Or is something different needed to append to an existing NSSet?

Comment: That won't work, again you need to use Core Data techniques. You can use `mutableSetValueForKey:` to get a set that you can modify. Or if Xcode is creating `NSManagedObject` subclasses for you (which is normal in Xcode 8) then you have methods like `addStepsObject` and `addSteps` that are more convenient.

Answer (score -2):

To add new managed object use the below code.

Steps *steps = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Steps" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext];

//now you have the Steps object, if want to add values to the object you can add also.

//now save the moc

still have any doubt plz let me know.